# Windows 10 - Folder opens with a long delay after clicking on Pinned Folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Windows 10 - Folder opens with a long delay after clicking on Pinned Folder.
I have noticed that this problem does not occur with a fresh Windows Installation but after either we install Windows updates.

[Video for the issue](https://jmp.sh/Wk57PGR)

Comment: You could try to rebuild the Index and clearing File Explorer History and resetting the switch for 'Show recently open items in Jump Lists'. 
Type “Index” in Search Bar and open Indexing Options>Advanced>Rebuild.
Windows Explorer>View>Options>Folder Options>General>Privacy>Clear

Comment: I can't see a long delay in your video.

Comment: @harrymc: It is a 3-4 seconds delay. As with a new windows installation, its instant

Comment: @daidai: let me try this

Comment: @TamourAhmad , if you are frequently switching between folders, please be aware that you can open multiple File Explorer windows.  Right-click on the yellow File Explorer icon in the taskbar and choose "File Explorer".  Then you don't have to wait as much switching between directories in a single window.

Answer (score 2):

I know this might be a bit late, it's been a few months, but I would like to contribute for anyone experiencing the problem. I had the same exact issue, and looked in various forums trying to find the answer, until I found it myself. For me, it was the Google Drive Backup and Sync app. With the app closed, everything went back to normal.

So, if you use Google Drive as well, it might be the culprit.

Comment: I do have Google Drive installed and Configured. Let me try and confirm back.

Comment: I'm just curious. Did it fix your problem?

Comment: Nope it didn't fix it. Although I have noticed, In Windows 10, if you select "This PC" for "Open File Explorer to" in Folder Options; it does speed up.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as it sounds, try deleting the problematic pinned folder, and repinning it after performing the update to see if that solves the issue.

More than likely it is caused either by windows modifying the indexing or how the data is stored of the drive (e.g. it's everywhere). It is also possible that with the updates it creates additional references that are followed before the actual data location is accessed. There are too many possibilites without being able to take a look at the system directly. Worst case scenario is that it's a hardware problem with the disk.

Comment: There is no problematic pinned folder. The delay is not in opening the menu from taskbar but the time it takes to open folder after we click the folder.
I have SSD.

Comment: Correct. A pinned folder is simply a reference to the actual directory. I'm not going to explain how it works, but there are multiple possibilities as to why a link isn't "instant". People are accustomed to things being instant; however the processor is juggling multiple tasks at once and completes tasks based on priority. Multiple drive I/O streams, processes, etc. can lengthen or shorten the directory access time. As mentioned above, your delay is less than two seconds, and shouldn't be causing too much concern.

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I found that it was a pinned folder that is secured and need a password the first time I use it. Once logged the pinned folders menu open right away without any delay.